# Are there any strict rules for naming app packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

I was creating app for my website. I decided to create two. One would be simple looking and the other one would be fancy. I created the fancy one first with the package name UmerSoftwares.app.stl and then I tried to create the simple one with the package name UmerSoftwares.app.simple but it gave me the error while running:
[Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRkrM.png) INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED. I tried deleting the project and creating one again with the same project name UmerSoftwares.app.simple but it gave me the same error (There was nothing coded this time and it was a simple hello world project). Then I created another project with the package name com.UmerSoftwares.app and it worked without any problem. I wanted to ask why?
If there are any compulsory rules for naming projects then please tell me because I didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android `PackageParser` that reads the APK at installation time requires the package name to start with a lowercase letter `a..z` on Android versions before 7.0 Nougat.

I have not seen documentation for this, but I've debugged similar "manifest malformed" issues by reading the [source](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java#1949).